# How to add a delete/remove button per each option item in html select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create or use a library to create a custom HTML `<select>` to delete each item in the HTML `<select>`. Something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> <button>delete</button>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option> <button>delete</button>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option> <button>delete</button>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> <button>delete</button>
</select>
```

I have searched how to do this and for any library that might exist to do this, but I haven't found anything. In iOS exists [this](http://vivacocoa.jp/app/ios/nota-ios/nota-ios-img/delete-row_en.png).  I need something like that but for HTML.

**UPDATE:** Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/b22ww/2/

Comment: I think you need something like a listview, not a select.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="list" value="volvo">Volvo <button>delete</button></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="list" value="saab">Saab <button>delete</button></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="list" value="mercedes">Mercedes <button>delete</button></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="list" value="mercedes">Mercedes <button>delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Then add event listeners to each button that removes the parent `<li>` from the list ([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/CdLaY/)).

Comment: And with some heavy jQuery work, you could refactor this so it makes a factor drop down select.  There is probably a jQuery UI plugin that already does this.

Comment: thanks this is so helpful with using this another example http://jsfiddle.net/Tpf7E/22/

Answer (score 3):

What you need to achieve, it's quite impossible using `select`. What you need is to create something like a `listview`, like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>item one <div class='deleteMe'>X</div></li>
    <li>item two <div class='deleteMe'>X</div></li>
    <li>item three <div class='deleteMe'>X</div></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

and bind a click handler

**JS**

```
$(".deleteMe").on("click", function(){
   $(this).closest("li").remove(); 
});
```

see this example

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/zZ3mc/

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using jQuery plugins, [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) allows you to customize select elements. In your case, look at the section called "Selected and Disabled Support".

Answer (score 1):

I have done Something like this...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".deleteMe").on("click", function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
      $(this).closest("li").remove();
    } else {
      return false
    }
    return false;
  });
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).text());
    $('#selected').html('<img class="trigger" src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFSrX.png">' + $(this).text().trim().slice(0, -1));
    $('.dropdown-container').hide();
  });
  $(window).click(function() {
    $(".dropdown").css("border", "1px solid #444");
    $('.dropdown-container').hide();
 });
  $("#selected").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".dropdown").css("border", "1px solid orange");
    $('.dropdown-container').show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
  li {
    list-style: none;
    background: white;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .deleteMe {
    float: right;
    color: red;
  }

  .dropdown-container {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    width: 290px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  li:hover {
    background-color: #ead6b7;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 300px;
    height:30px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 3px;
  }
  .dropdown .trigger {
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 1px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selected" class="dropdown">
  <img class="trigger" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFSrX.png"> Select Something!
</div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display:none">
  <li>item one selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item two selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item three selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item four selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item five selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item six selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item seven selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item eight selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item nine selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
  <li>item ten selected
    <div class='deleteMe'>X</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

I hope this will help some one!

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid HTML. You cannot do this.

You can do this using a SIMULATED select (a bunch of HTML/JS that behaves like a select, but is not one)

Comment: Then I'd add that if (s)he's planning to pass that in a form, he'd need to serialize or do something else with those elements in order to be included in the package sent back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the button within the select. One alternate option is to move it outside the select, as in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8kByh/).

html:

```
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button>Delete current choice</button>
```

Sample script:

```
var button=document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0],
    select=document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
button.onclick=function(){
    select.removeChild(select.options[select.selectedIndex]);
};
```